# Change in XML serialization related to nillable attribute

Tags: .net, xml, xsd, xml-serialization

I would like to know if anyone knows about some change in dot net libraries, that causes different way of serialization on nillable elements. Three months ago, our system was producing this kind of element, in case related property was null:

```
<LatinFirstName />
```

XSD for this elements looks like this:

```
            <xsd:element name="LatinFirstName" minOccurs="0"
                nillable="true">
                <xsd:simpleType>
                    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                        <xsd:maxLength value="70"></xsd:maxLength>
                        <xsd:pattern
                            value="[&quot;\\/\(\)\-'\.,_:a-zA-Z]+">
                        </xsd:pattern>
                    </xsd:restriction>
                </xsd:simpleType>
            </xsd:element>
```

However, something changed and system is currently producing this on same place:

```
<LatinFirstName p5:nil="true" xmlns:p5="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
```

I'm trying to figure out what caused this change and potentially way how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this happened after you rebuild the code, the behavior will not change with a .net update. So the question is what got changed between the builds that caused this.

But looking at your xml schema definition the "new" output is in the correct format. The "old" output will be invalid when validated against the schema.

when you serialize an object the serializer checks if the properties are initialized. if the property is not and still has a null value it will skip it by default. This passes validation because of the minoccurs = 0;

If the property is initialized with a "" or a space the serializer will serialize the property and you will get an empty tag (or a space if you defined preserve whitespaces). This is still valid xml but the restriction in your xsd does not allow an empty element. If the element is present it must comply with the restrictions.
By adding the nillable=true in the xsd you make this valid again.
The serializer sees that the property is initialized but the content of the property is empty and if the property is defined with "[XmlElement(IsNullable=true)]" it will add the nillable=true to the xml message.